Append cell in postgresql
I have the table in POSTGRESQL. How can insert row if in the table is not exist or update if exist by appending array in last table (Adding to the array should add new text in last column, like "1. First;" "1. First;2.Second;" "1. First;2.Second;2.Second;" etc)?
This is my code that I want to use:
INSERT INTO public.history (arm_number, dt_action)
VALUES ('1', '{"1. First;"}')
ON CONFLICT (arm_number)
DO UPDATE SET dt_action = ARRAY_APPEND(EXCLUDED.dt_action, '2. Second;');

When I use it i got only "1. First;2.Second;" What should I do?

Works fine over here, when using an ARRAY:
CREATE TABLE public.history(arm_number int PRIMARY KEY , dt_action text[]);

INSERT INTO public.history (arm_number, dt_action)
VALUES ('1', '{"1. First;"}')
ON CONFLICT (arm_number)
DO UPDATE SET dt_action = ARRAY_APPEND(EXCLUDED.dt_action, '2. Second;');

INSERT INTO public.history (arm_number, dt_action)
VALUES ('1', '{"1. First;"}')
ON CONFLICT (arm_number)
DO UPDATE SET dt_action = ARRAY_APPEND(EXCLUDED.dt_action, '2. Second;');

SELECT arm_number
     , unnest(dt_action)
FROM public.history;

Result:
1,1. First;
1,2. Second;

This is not what I need. I need  sql query that will add new data at the end of the row to an existing cell with text, every time. Like this

"1.First;"
after 1st append:
"1.First;2.Second"
after 2nd append:
"1.First;2.Second;2.Second"
etc...


I found my mistake. It was necessary to write "history.dt_action" instead of "EXCLUDED.dt_action"
Below is the final code.
INSERT INTO public.history (arm_number, dt_action)
VALUES ('1', '{"1. First;"}')
ON CONFLICT (arm_number)
DO UPDATE SET dt_action = ARRAY_APPEND(history.dt_action, '2. Second;');

